# Register and login page checking if user exists

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I have been following a tutorial on youtube for a register and login page the register work but it allows me to register the same details over and over.

the code is as follows

```
if(IsPostBack)
           {
               SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["regConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
               conn.Open();
               string checkuser = "select count(*) from users where username='"+ Usernametxt.Text +"'";
               SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
               int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
               if (temp == 1)
               {
                   Response.Write("User already exists");
               }
               conn.Close();
           }
        }
```

therefore it is bypassing this code and when it should say user already exists can anyone see a problem with the code or offer a solution

Comment: Your question is not clear. Have you debugged the code? What is the value of `temp`? One big problem that I can see in your code is that it is open for `SQL Injection attack!`

Comment: Note - You should look into sql injection because your code is currently vulnerable to it

Comment: its just for a uni project so it wont be going live its just so a user can login and register thats all, yeah ive debugged the code

Comment: you could try, greater than or equal to one (>=1). probably you have already greater than one entry for that user. You may also try to use SqlDataReader, where you can use the HasValue property to determine if the value is already present in the database. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use !IsPostBack code not use in only  IsPostBack

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if(IsPostBack)
{
   SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["regConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
   conn.Open();
   string checkuser = "SELECT TOP 1 username FROM users WHERE username='"+ Usernametxt.Text +"'";
   SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
   string temp = com.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(temp))
   {
       Response.Write("User already exists");
   }
   conn.Close();
}
```

with this you only search in the table until find one record (`TOP 1`), and not the entire table (`COUNT(*)`)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but it can be possible that the username has been added for more than one time already while testing .So its better if you use

```
if (temp > 0)
           {
               Response.Write("User already exists");
           }
           conn.Close();
```

Anyways, If this is to register a user,i prefer checking the username in the database by using a procedure that gives out a 1 if username does not exist and gives out a -1 if the username already exists and then you can write the code in code-behind accordingly.